# c# search ms access db by ID

Tags: c#, ms-access, search

```
private void Filtriraj()
    {
        string filter = string.Empty;
        if (txtID.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            filter = "ID LIKE '%" + txtID.Text + "%'";
        }
        if (txtName.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            filter = "Name LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%'";
        }
    }
```

I want to search thru ms access db tables in my c# app. The one above is connected to "Table1" that has some fields like ID, name, surname, address...ID type is set to autonumber, all others are to text. I'm able to search all fields except by ID, this way above wont work, i get exception when i try to search by ID (I type in txtbox some ID number that is in db, exmp: '1')
Search by txtName is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Autonumber is some form of number (long I think) so you can't use the LIKE keyword. You must search for an exact match (or greather than, less than etc.). You also can't surround a number with single quotes, so those will need to be removed.

I'd switch your code to something like this:

```
.
.
.
if (txtID.Text.Length > 0)
{
    int id;
    if (Int32.TryParse(txtID.Text, out id))
    {
        filter = "ID = " + id.ToString();
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Also, your code looks like it may not work properly if you have multiple text boxes filled with data (because you are not using else if). Whatever text box you check last will end up being the filter that gets used because you're reassigning the filter variable each time. And if you're using the filter text directly from the text boxes, you're opening yourself up to possible [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should probably look into using [parameterized queries](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2006/01/05/parameterized-queries-and-performance/).

Comment: Ok, I'm still clueless about how to search for an exact match

Comment: @djuvec12: I added an example. The TryParse is to ensure that the ID text box actually contains a number. Otherwise you'll get an error when you try to search the ID field if the user enters something like ABC.

Comment: @djuvec12: No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct by checking off the little check box. ;)

Comment: by the way, autonumber fields are signed 32-bit integers. That's a `Long` in VBA, or an `int` in C#. The Access table designer calls it a "Long Integer" (except when it's an autonumber field, of course).

Comment: @phoog: Oops... I haven't worked with Access in a few years, so I just assumed the autonumber was a 64-bit like most other databases. I've changed my example.